# How to find gradle subproject tasks from different working directory

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I'm running into the problem that my gradle wrapper will only find subprojects if I execute it whilst being in the same working directory. For example:

Let's say the project structure is as follows:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── ...
├── build.gradle
├── gradlew
├── settings.gradle
└── ...
```

It makes a difference whether I run gradlew from it's directory or from a different directory. If I run:

```
$ ./gradlew projects

> Task :projects

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Root project 'com.name'
+--- Project ':app'
```

it has no problem finding `:app`. However, if I navigate and execute gradlew from a folder up, it cannot find it:

```
$ cd ..
$ ./android/gradlew projects

> Task :projects

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Root project 'com'
No sub-projects
```

It can't find the projects. This is problematic for me since I need to run a task in `:app` from a pipeline from a different working directory, e.g. `./xx/yy/gradlew app:publishTask`. However doing it this way, gradle can't find the task because it can't find the project. Is there a way to run these commands from any location?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. You have to:

1. store your current location in an temporary variable
2. change location to project directory
3. run ./gradlew
4. restore directory from variable

ex:

```
TMP_DIR=`pwd`
cd /path/to/project
./gradlew projects
cd $TMP_DIR
```